Unusual answer for signals & systems problem
I'm stuck at part d) of the problem.
While my solution for the output signal after simplified is: \$y[n] = u[n] + u[n-2]\$, the provided answer: \$y[n] = 2u[n] - \delta[n] - \delta[n - 1]\$ with \$\delta[n]\$ is the unit impulse.
I can't really understand how the unit impulse appears within the equation and really need some help with the explaination of this anwser. Or maybe the answer itself is inaccurate?


EDIT:
1. Source: Book Signals & Systems, second Edition, by Alan S. Willsky and Alan V. Oppenheim , Prentice Hall, problem 2.7 of chapter two (Linear Time Invariant Systems), pages 138 and 139.
2. The informations on book are exactly those provided in this question. No missing data.

Or maybe the answer itself is inaccurate? <-- or maybe your interpretation of the answer is inaccurate. Nobody can tell without seeing an extract of where the answer is and then checking to see if there are any subsequent errata data published which, to be honest, you should really do. You also need to provide a citation for the image you currently have introduced into your question. If it's on-line then provide a link to the page.

@kuro please provide an attempt at the solution

I think OP already provided an answer; he just didn't show how he arrived at it. He is asking the reason why book's answer, mentioned in the edit, shows unitary impulses and his solution doesn't. As requested, additional details were provided after closing event, which alleged reason was "missing details or clarity". This no longer applies.

A hint: Unit impulse is the difference of an unit step and another unit step which is delayed one sample period from the first one. Two adjacent impulses need delay = 2 sample periods.
